# tomcat jersey retrieve full context path

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I'm implementing ApplicationEventListener, I need to retrieve the context path, the one declared in my web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I'm implementing onEvent method

```
@Override
public void onEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
    if (event.getType() == ApplicationEvent.Type.INITIALIZATION_FINISHED) {
        final ResourceModel resourceModel = event.getResourceModel();           
    }
}
```

I can also use `@Context ServletContext servletContext` in ResourceConfig to pass the info if necessary but I don't know how to reach this.

From a servlet using HttpServletRequest, it's possible to call  `request.getContextPath()`, but obviously I can't use HttpServletRequest.

Generally speaking, in my application I need a way to retrieve `servlet-mapping`

Thanks

Edit:
listener class: `org.glassfish.jersey.server.monitoring.ApplicationEventListe‌​ner`

Comment: Which is the full package of ApplicationEventListener?

Comment: org.glassfish.jersey.server.monitoring.ApplicationEventListener

Anyway I can also do this operation in my org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig  class but I don't know which class to use

Comment: What's the Servlet API version?

Comment: I'm on tomcat 8.5.11 so it's 3.1